# Extracting image from a page displayed in Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My app displays third party website pages in webview based on certain search. Now if user clicks on some image (e.g. small product image on a site), I'd like to capture that image in my app?

I can capture URL in shouldOverrideUrlLoading() in my app but don't know how to extract image out of it.

Any link/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the URL of the image, I'd suggest that you create an HttpURLConnection[1] to it, then decode the response into a Bitmap with BitmapFactory[2].

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

[2] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html